# DOMXPath - Get Node

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm facing an issue that I cannot resolve. I'm using [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.domxpath.php) to retrieve the value of `MsgId` tag of the following XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>Test/20171013/CCT100621</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2017-10-13T10:06:21</CreDtTm>
            <NbOfTxs>62</NbOfTxs>
        </GrpHdr>
    </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

The following is my PHP code snippet to query the XML with DOMXPath:

```
$xml = <<<XML
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
            <GrpHdr>
                <MsgId>Test/20171013/CCT100621</MsgId>
                <CreDtTm>2017-10-13T10:06:21</CreDtTm>
                <NbOfTxs>62</NbOfTxs>
            </GrpHdr>
        </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    </Document>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadXML($xml);
$groupHeaderXPath = new DOMXPath($document);
echo $groupHeaderXPath->query('//GrpHdr/MsgId')->length; // returns 0
```

I'm testing the query with this [tool](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output) and it seems that it is correct.

Has anybody an idea, why the xpath expression does not work in this context? Am I missing some details here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$groupHeaderXPath` is of type [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), which has a method [registerNamespace](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php).

I think it would help to register the namespace and use the prefix 'urn' in your xpath expression.

For example:

```
$rootNamespace = $document->lookupNamespaceUri($document->namespaceURI);
$groupHeaderXPath->registerNamespace("urn", $rootNamespace);
echo $groupHeaderXPath->query('//urn:GrpHdr/urn:MsgId')->length; // returns 1
```

Comment: This is the issue. If you remove the namespace it will work fine because everything is in the default namespace.